# Is there a way to change Views in iOS without using UINavigationController?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

I have a login page at the beginning of my app that I do not want on the view stack.  Is there a way to load my first post-login view after the login without using `UINavigatorController`?

Is there a better way to be doing this?  Should I be using 2 `UINavigationControllers`?  Is there a way to change the `RootViewController` for a `UINavigationController`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can change root controller of window. Set window's property `rootViewController` to new controller and you're done. Don't forget though that first controller (one you are removing) will not receive `viewWillDisappear:` and `viewDidDisappear:` messages. Send them yourself before switching controllers if you're interested in them.

Comment: Sorry, I know this is a total newb question, but how do I get access to my app's window object from within any given View Controller's code?

Comment: Well it's not usually a good idea to manipulate window from controllers (it's better to move such logic to some central object, like app delegate), but if you really need this you can find window either by going up on view hierarchy until you reach `UIWindow` instance or (preferred way) you can get key window with `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]`

Comment: I tried 

`MyViewController.view.window.rootViewController = MyViewController;`

but it didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: I got it working by using viewControllers and setViewControllers on the UINavigationController, but this seems dirty.

I tried `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]` and also had no luck when setting the rootViewController property.

Comment: Documentation states for `window` property of `UIView`: `The receiver’s window object, or nil if it has none.` Since your MyViewController's view isn't added to any window this property will return nil. That's why you are not observing any effect. I wrote how to retrieve app's window in above comment. P.S. It's better not to start instance names with capital letter because it's confusing.

Comment: 'I tried [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] and also...' Are you sure value you are trying to set isn't nil? That's the only reason I can think about now.

Comment: @hoha When I assign new controller to [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow], how to do with old controller(eg:LoginViewController)? Releaes it?Remove it ?

Comment: @qichunren You should only release it if you own it (e.g. in some instance variable). That is if you are not using ARC of course. Window will automatically remove old controller from screen.

Answer (score 0):

You might also look at [UIViewController#presentViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController%3aanimated%3acompletion%3a)